# Bringing bottled soda on Air France / Philippine Airlines flight to Manila

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, food-and-drink, philippines

I will soon be flying from Europe to Singapore SIN via Paris CDG (checked through luggage) and then board a separate flight from Singapore to Manila NAIA.

I'm visiting a friend and I'd love to bring them a few bottles of "local" soda, but I'm still unsure about whether I can carry those in my checked in baggage without any complications. The soda is sold in glass bottles of 0.75 liters.

The flight to Singapore is with Air France, while the Singapore to Manila flight is with Philippine Airlines.

I also considered buying the beverage in the duty-free zone (if available) and bringing it in my carry on luggage, although I then wondered whether that will work considering I have to go through security again at Singapore Changi Airport.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

---

**TLDR**: Flight to SIN via CDG followed by additional SIN to MNL flight. Need to re-clear security at SIN. How do I bring soda to my friend?

Comment: To be clear, your origin airport is CDG, your destination is MNL, and you are transiting SIN? I'm just asking because you say "flight to SIN via CDG" and that suggests you're transiting CDG.

Comment: Sorry, should've clarified. I'm flying from TXL (Berlin) to SIN via CDG and will then board another flight from SIN to MNL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Liquids in checked luggage is generally fine, although there some local rule specifically for alcohol. A few bottles of soda should not pose a problem. You need to pack them properly since the checked baggage gets banged around quite a bit and you should monitor your weight limits.

Carry on is not a good idea. It's very hard to predict whether you will get another security screening during a connection.

Comment: *It's very hard to predict whether you will get another security screening during a connection.* In this case it's very easy. At Changi, security is at the gate, so they will definitely be checked.

Answer (score 3):

> I also considered buying the beverage in the duty-free zone (if available) and bringing it in my carry on luggage, although I then wondered whether that will work considering I have to go through security again at Singapore Changi Airport.

Since no one else has addressed this possibility, security at Changi allow liquids through which have been bought airside and are in sealed tamper evident bags (and subject to the laws of the destination country). Since security at Changi is at the gate, duty free liquids bought at Changi are routinely provided in tamper-evident bags, so security there are used to seeing them. If you are able to buy your soda at duty free in France and they can provide it in a tamper-evident bag, then you have a very good chance of it being allowed through to Manilla (although I can't guarantee it obviously).

Answer (score 0):

Soda is likely to be refused and confiscated if you proffer it as carry-on. Whether this occurs will be up to the security rules imposed at the departure airport.

The way to bring soda to your friend is to buy it post-security but before boarding your last flight segment.

Comment: I think the problem is that OP wants to bring some particular type of soda which is available in France, but not in Singapore.

Comment: @NateEldredge Perhaps so. That'd be a challenge. MJeffryes suggests a possible solution in his answer.